# Inserting a new element into linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="JsonData" method="post">
<br>
  Previous stop: <input type="text" name="pre"><br>
  Next stop: <input type="text" name="nxt"><br>
  Latitude: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
  Longitude: <input type="text" name="longitude"><br>
  Type: <input type="text" name="type"><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Servlet code:

```
public class InsertPos extends HttpServlet
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


     List<JSONObject> linkedList = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();

        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {

            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            double lat =Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("latitude"));
            double lon =Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("longitude"));
            String type=request.getParameter("type");
            int pre=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("pre"));
            int nxt=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("nxt"));

            JSONObject obj1=new JSONObject();



        try 
        {
            if(nxt==999&&type.equals("v"))
            {
                System.out.println("Inserting Object Before a Via["type":"v"]" );
                obj1.put("lat", lat);
                obj1.put("lon", lon);
                obj1.put("type", type);
                int i=pre+1;
                linkedList.add(i, obj1);

                JSONArray alsit = new JSONArray(linkedList);
                System.out.println(alsit);

            }
            else if(pre==999&&type.equals("s"))
            {   
                System.out.println("Inserting Object After a Via["type":"v"]" );
                JSONArray alsit = new JSONArray(linkedList);
                int insertAtIndexForJSONArray = findInsertAtIndex(alsit,nxt);

                insertValue(insertAtIndexForJSONArray,alsit,lat,lon,type);


                System.out.println("New JSON Array :"+alsit);
            }
            else 
            {
                obj1.put("lat", lat);
                obj1.put("lon", lon);
                obj1.put("type", type);
                linkedList.add(nxt, obj1);

                JSONArray alsit = new JSONArray(linkedList);
                System.out.println(alsit);
            }

        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        }


        private static int findInsertAtIndex(JSONArray ja, int i) throws JSONException 
        {

            int curIndex =0;
            int reqIndex=0;
            for(int j=0;j<ja.length();j++){
                JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(j);;
                if(jo.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
                     if(curIndex==i){
                            reqIndex=j;
                            break;
                        }
                        curIndex++;
                }
            }

            return reqIndex;
        }
        private static void insertValue(int index, JSONArray ja,double lat,double lon,String t) throws JSONException 
        {

             JSONArray ja1= new JSONArray();
            //Copy the data from that index in another JSONArray
            //It is an array, so you will need to do shifting
            for(int i=index;i<ja.length();i++){
                ja1.put(ja.get(i));
            }
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
            jo.put("lat", lat);
            jo.put("lon", lon);
            jo.put("type", t);
            ja.put(index, jo);;

            int shiftIndex = index+1;
            for(int i=0;i<ja1.length();i++){
                ja.put(shiftIndex,ja1.get(i));
                shiftIndex++;
            }


        }


}
```

If I Run for the 1st time,will provide pre & nxt as 0,0 respectively ,So now the else part is executed  -at 0th index inserted 
    [{"lon":77.57200874383307,"type":"s","lat":12.905683932781095}]

For the second time will give pre &nxt as 0,1 respectively ,So again else part is executed.
    [{"lon":77.46553577478217,"type":"s","lat":12.894117321535727},{"lon":77.57200874383307,"type":"s","lat":12.905683932781095}]

For third time will insert a "v" b/w 0&1 ,So again else part is executed
  [{"lon":77.46553577478217,"type":"s","lat":12.894117321535727},{"lon":77.54596985871751,"type":"v","lat":12.878199284620463},{"lon":77.57200874383307,"type":"s","lat":12.905683932781095}]

Now I insert "v" again b/w 0 & 1 ,here index 1 contains "type":"v",So will provide pre as 0 & nxt as 999 as next point is via,The  if(nxt==999&&type.equals("v")) is executed.

[{"lon":77.46553577478217,"type":"s","lat":12.894117321535727},{"lon":77.56673430067228,"type":"v","lat":12.893814030683414},{"lon":77.54596985871751,"type":"v","lat":12.878199284620463},{"lon":77.57200874383307,"type":"s","lat":12.905683932781095}]

Now I insert a point before the last point,User will consider only "s" & provides pre as 999(its a "v") & nxt as 1 ,In our code this part is executed else if(pre==999&&type.equals("s"))

New JSON Array :[{"lon":77.46553577478217,"type":"s","lat":12.894117321535727},{"lon":77.56673430067228,"type":"v","lat":12.893814030683414},{"lon":77.54596985871751,"type":"v","lat":12.878199284620463},{"lon":77.5358620557242,"type":"s","lat":12.900077980951266},{"lon":77.57200874383307,"type":"s","lat":12.905683932781095}]
Successfully got it inserted

Suppose if I add another point after the newly inserted point,In this case if i add after 3rd index ,Will provide index as 1 & 2 as user wont consider "v"

**Current o/p :**
[{"lon":77.46553577478217,"type":"s","lat":12.894117321535727},{"lon":77.56673430067228,"type":"v","lat":12.893814030683414},{"lon":77.48705658049113,"type":"s","lat":12.892861822540487},{"lon":77.54596985871751,"type":"v","lat":12.878199284620463},{"lon":77.57200874383307,"type":"s","lat":12.905683932781095}]

The problem i am facing is
last inserted data is getting erased as you can see int o/p the 3rd index is override d & also new data is getting inserted at index 2,which should be inserted at 4th index

**Expected out/put :**
[{"lon":77.46553577478217,"type":"s","lat":12.894117321535727},{"lon":77.56673430067228,"type":"v","lat":12.893814030683414},{"lon":77.54596985871751,"type":"v","lat":12.878199284620463},{"lon":77.5358620557242,"type":"s","lat":12.900077980951266},
**{"lon":77.48705658049113,"type":"s","lat":12.892861822540487},**{"lon":77.57200874383307,"type":"s","lat":12.905683932781095}]

Comment: It's not at all clear where the Z comes from, or what the 0 and 1 actually mean. You really need to clarify your question - as well as showing what you've tried and what problems you've run into. I'd also *strongly* encourage you to rename your class from `Linkedlist` - having two classes which differ only be capitalization of a single letter is asking for trouble. If each element in the list is logically a pair of values, you may well want to create a class for that rather than keeping it as a string, too...

Comment: Please check my original problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530542/inserting-new-element-based-on-index-in-linked-list

Comment: No, please edit your question to be clearer. Each question should stand alone - we shouldn't need to read another question in order to understand this one.

Comment: No actually that was my question , no one answerd that So asked a simple question here

Comment: Your question isn't simple - at least, it's not simple to understand. You need to clarify it. I don't know how many different ways I can say that. (And you should really have clarified your existing question instead of asking a new one.)

Comment: Ok leave it..I have list with elements now i want to insert new one by giving the index,The user gives index which has a string " :1" ,So he gives 0 &1 based on this i have to count the index which has last as ":1" & insert after that

Comment: Repeating what you've already said in the question isn't the same as clarifying the question. I'm done here - hopefully you'll *actually* clarify the question to the point where someone else can help you... but you really need to put effort into making it *very* clear what you're asking. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Sorry please ask me what is the doubt you have

Comment: I am trying to insert new element into linked list

Comment: Z is the new element that i am trying to insert ,0 & 1 are the index

Comment: @RamL: No body can assume what you are trying to do. You should provide detail examples of where you need exactly to insert. The example you gave was pretty bad. Please try to be more clear

Comment: Can you please check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29626246/inserting-values-into-js-using-ajax?noredirect=1#comment47395895_29626246 Need your answer for this

Answer (score 0):

As `Jon` mention in comment, you should mention where you want to insert, what are `i` and `j` of `insertStop` method. if you want to insert at a particular index, you have to use `add` method.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        // add elements to the linked list
        list.add("F:1");//0
        list.add("B:v");
        list.add("D:v");
        list.add("E:v");
        list.add("C:1");//1
        list.add("M:x");
        list.add("N:1");//2
        list.add("K:y");
        list.add("L:s");
        list.add("O:1");//3
        System.out.println("Old List :"+list);

        int insertAtIndex=findInsertAtIndex(list,1,2);
        //Here I do not know, what are i and j
        //I can assume that  between 2 consecutive you will need to insert
        //What is the use of giving 1st index then
        //This is not clear here
        insertValue(insertAtIndex,list);
        System.out.println("New List After Inserting :"+list);

   }

    private static int findInsertAtIndex(List<String> list,int i,int j) {
        int curIndex =0;
        int reqIndex=0;
        for(int k=0;k<list.size();k++){
            if(list.get(k).endsWith(":1")){
                if(curIndex==j){
                    reqIndex=k;
                    break;
                }
                curIndex++;

            }
        }
        return reqIndex;
    }
   private static void insertValue(int insertIndex, List<String> list) {
       list.add(insertIndex, "Z:1");

   }

}
```

**Output**

```
Old List :[F:1, B:v, D:v, E:v, C:1, M:x, N:1, K:y, L:s, O:1]
New List After Inserting :[F:1, B:v, D:v, E:v, C:1, M:x, Z:1, N:1, K:y, L:s, O:1]
```

**Edit: Added Code for JSONArray**
`JSONArray is **not** a LINKEDLIST`

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {


        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "F");
        jo.put("type", "1");
        ja.put(jo);

        jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "B");
        jo.put("type", "v");
        ja.put(jo);

        jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "D");
        jo.put("type", "v");
        ja.put(jo);

        jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "E");
        jo.put("type", "v");
        ja.put(jo);

        jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "C");
        jo.put("type", "1");
        ja.put(jo);

        jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "M");
        jo.put("type", "x");
        ja.put(jo);

        jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "N");
        jo.put("type", "1");
        ja.put(jo);

        jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "K");
        jo.put("type", "y");
        ja.put(jo);

        jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "L");
        jo.put("type", "s");
        ja.put(jo);

        jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "O");
        jo.put("type", "1");
        ja.put(jo);

        System.out.println("Old JSON Array :"+ja);

        int insertAtIndexForJSONArray = findInsertAtIndex(ja,2);

        insertValue(insertAtIndexForJSONArray,ja);


        System.out.println("New JSON Array :"+ja);

   }

    private static void insertValue(int index, JSONArray ja) throws JSONException {

        JSONArray ja1= new JSONArray();
        //Copy the data from that index in another JSONArray
        //It is an array, so you will need to do shifting
        for(int i=index;i<ja.length();i++){
            ja1.put(ja.get(i));
        }
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
        jo.put("lon", "Z");
        jo.put("type", "1");
        ja.put(index, jo);

        int shiftIndex = index+1;
        for(int i=0;i<ja1.length();i++){
            ja.put(shiftIndex,ja1.get(i));
            shiftIndex++;
        }


    }

    private static int findInsertAtIndex(JSONArray ja, int i) throws JSONException {

        int curIndex =0;
        int reqIndex=0;
        for(int j=0;j<ja.length();j++){
            JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(j);
            if(jo.getString("type").equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                 if(curIndex==i){
                        reqIndex=j;
                        break;
                    }
                    curIndex++;
            }
        }

        return reqIndex;
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Old JSON Array :[{"lon":"F","type":"1"},{"lon":"B","type":"v"},{"lon":"D","type":"v"},{"lon":"E","type":"v"},{"lon":"C","type":"1"},{"lon":"M","type":"x"},{"lon":"N","type":"1"},{"lon":"K","type":"y"},{"lon":"L","type":"s"},{"lon":"O","type":"1"}]
New JSON Array :[{"lon":"F","type":"1"},{"lon":"B","type":"v"},{"lon":"D","type":"v"},{"lon":"E","type":"v"},{"lon":"C","type":"1"},{"lon":"M","type":"x"},{"lon":"Z","type":"1"},{"lon":"N","type":"1"},{"lon":"K","type":"y"},{"lon":"L","type":"s"},{"lon":"O","type":"1"}]
```

**Note: I am using Jettison JSONArray**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74953/discussion-on-answer-by-vivek-vardhan-inserting-a-new-element-into-linked-list).

Comment: @Vivek Vardhan Please check the updated question with scenario's